# Concentration inequalities without independence assumption

Tags: probability-theory

Can one give some examples of concentration inequalities , other than Markov and Chebyshev's inequalities, that do not have independence assumption?

Comment: Paley–Zygmund inequality

Comment: take a look at the book "Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence" by  Boucheron, Lugosi and Massar